# How do I assign a default value to a UITextField?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

My iOS app crashes every time a user hits 'next' when one of the fields (they're strings) is empty.  How do I make it to where this doesn't happen?

```
emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:nameField.text];
```

Here's one of the lines that is causing the crash; it's trying to pull the data from nameField.text, but in some cases it's empty and this crashes it.

Comment: Dont leave them empty...put `@" "`, if some thing else is not effected

Comment: How do I set nameField.text = @""; then?  Typing this produces an error.

Comment: What's the error when it crashes? What is the code that crashes? There is nothing wrong with empty text fields. But obviously your code is making a bad assumption somewhere.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya There is no need to set the text to `@" "`. The solution is to fix the problem code, not mask it with an inappropriate hack.

Comment: I posted the comment before, seeing the code. now i can say, he might have missed to alloc+init `emailbody` or email body is not `string`. His code is perfect, no issues

Comment: @rmaddy is right, his/her problem is not empty text fields as if there is nothing typed in a textfield then its string is always `@""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't assign a default value - instead you should secure your code so it does not crash.

In this case, you could do the following:

```
if (nameField.text) {
    emailBody = [emailBody stringByAppendingString:nameField.text];
}
```